# discord.py Selfbot can't get guild users

Tags: discord.py

Intro:
I am working on a project where i need selfbot to return all guild users it is in, for past week tried lots of things discord.js , discord.py official api, but am not able to achieve my goal, actually i did it once but am not able to replicate the code that did it.

What am i doing:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def dmall(ctx, content):
    for members in bot.get_all_members():
        print(members)
```

another example:

```
 for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
```

Well actually there is much more but those are latest.

What happens:

This returns my and bot ids only with user token.

I want to get all ids from the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Selfbot cant get all members, just part of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413043/discord-selfbot-cant-get-all-members-just-part-of-it)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5782#issuecomment-707908993
Look at it. You have to enable intents for your bot, especially the server members intent (from the discord dev portal).

Then, in your code, do this:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents = intents, **kwargs) # OR COMMANDS.BOT
```

I'm not sure that this will work, but give it a try. I'm not going to test it cause selfbot are forbidden.