# Can discord.py self bots fetch the server members?

Tags: discord.py

I know self-bots are against the TOS. This is for my own understanding.

```
for user in ctx.guild.members:
```

Will this work in a Discord.py self bot?

Comment: You're gonna have a faster answer if you simply try it...

Comment: It will work for your own servers/servers with only a few people. However it is mostly not possible from what I have seen/tried. It will only catch a few members and if you try to fetch them you have to re-login and get an error in your console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Selfbot cant get all members, just part of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413043/discord-selfbot-cant-get-all-members-just-part-of-it)

Answer (score 0):

You have got the idea right but `ctx` doesn't work on discord.py-self

Instead of using `ctx` you can use `message.channel.guild` & that would work but if you want the member count just user `guild.member_count`

Reference: https://discordpy-self.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=game#discord.Guild.members